# Access SQL: Mapping two tables but with conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say, I have a table T1 looking like this:

```
ID |  Name |  Value        |  Flag
-------------------------------------
1  |   A   | (0) Something |  Alpha
1  |   A   | (2) Inaccurate|  Beta
2  |   B   | (4) Something |  Alpha
2  |   B   | (5) Inaccurate|  Beta
2  |   B   | (0) Something |  Gamma
```

and a table T2 looking like this:

```
ID |  Name |  Value        |  
----------------------------
1  |   A   |     X         | 
2  |   B   |     X         | 
2  |   B   |     W         |
```

What I want to do is:

1. I want to create a new table T3 with all the data from T1 except where Flag = Beta since their values are not accurate.
2. Then I want to map the more accurate data from T2 for those with Flag = Beta but only if T2 only has one value for this ID. Otherwise I want to have an error value instead.

Current result:

1. is no problem
2. is a bit problematic since I don't know how to include If-clauses. So basically something like:

   ```
   INSERT INTO T3 (ID, Name, Value, Flag) 
   SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, 
          IIF(
              LEN(
                  SELECT DISTINCT Value 
                  FROM T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID) 
          = 1, T2.Value, 'Error'), 
          T1.Flag 
   FROM T1 
   INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
   WHERE (T1.Flag = 'Beta' AND T1.ID = T2.ID)
   ```

This though does not work and throws:

> Error 3075 "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic is not far off.  I think we can just join to a subquery on the second table which identifies `ID` values having only one record.  This would indicate an accurate and reliable value to potentially be used for those beta records in the first table.

```
INSERT INTO T3 (ID, Name, Value, Flag) 
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, NZ(T2.Value, T1.Value), T1.Flag
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(Value)
    FROM T2
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.Flag = 'Beta'
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your suggestion!

So the subquery with